# What does string 'ai' mean in a URL?

Tags: url, urlencode

The link is as `www.googleadservice.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=(long chain of alphanumeric)`. What does **aclk?sa=L&ai** mean?

**EDIT**:

What does `ai` variable stands for? It contains long alphanumeric after `=` sign. 
*Does it mean affiliate ID*?

Comment: it is the get parameters..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

These are some attributes sent to the server. The server can access the values corresponding to each of the attributes like value of `sa` is `L`, so that it can generate the page or perform some operarions based on these values.

Answer (score 0):

This is all part of the URI (and URL).

The default scheme is `schema://host:port/path/file[?paramA=valA&paramB=valB]`

The addition after the ? is optional and called `Query  Parameter`, which gets parsed by the server - which receives your packet - so he can work with it. 
In php your read it with `$_GET["ai"]`.

**Information to your edit:**
WHAT a parameter is, depends on the implementation. I could only guess - and I guess it is something like an authentification hash, because it is so long.

Answer (score 0):

www.googleadservice.com/pagead/aclk -> URL
sa -> GET/Query parameter
ai -> GET/Query parameter

As the domain www.googleadservice.com is for sale, I can't tell you exactly what do those variables mean. If you have a link to a real API, you need to refer to that API's documentation. It can mean anything.